# Problema com select multiple em formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Desenvolvi um [site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk2iG.png) onde terá um formulário onde recebera um e-mail dentro desse formulário exite 2 `inputs select` porem o usuário irá poder selecionar mais de uma opção então adicionei a tag `multiple` logo ele poderá selecionar mais de um campo ao enviar o formulário ele funciona normalmente porem ele não recebe as outras opções do meu `select` se seleciono mais de uma opção no e-mail só aparece uma e as outras não, gostaria de saber como posso fazer aparecer as outras opções no e-mail segue a imagem de como é exibida no e-mail e os códigos.
Podem perceber no site selecionei mais de uma opção e no e-mail que chega só aparece uma delas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<form class="form-budget" id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 center">
                                    <div id="result"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="name" id="name" required/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu Email" name="email" id="email" required/>
                                <input type="tel" placeholder="Digite seu Telefone" name="phone" id="phone" class="phone_with_ddd" required/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Data do evento" name="date" id="date" class="date" required/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
                                        name="config" id="config"
                                        data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Configurações do evento">
                                    <option value="Mesas-Cadeiras">Mesas e cadeiras</option>
                                    <option value="Auditório">Auditório</option>
                                    <option value="Lounge">Lounge</option>
                                    <option value="Galeria">Galeria</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade de pessoas" name="quant" id="quant" class="quant" required/>

                                <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker" multiple
                                        data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Selecione os equipamentos"
                                        name="equip" id="equip" required>
                                    <option value="Projetor">Projetor</option>
                                    <option value="Som">Caixa de som</option>
                                    <option value="Flip-Chart">Flip-Chart</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_btn">Enviar orçamento</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

JS:

```
//Contact Us
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_date       = $('input[name=date]').val();
    var user_config     = $('select[name=config] option:selected').val();
    var user_quant      = $('input[name=quant]').val();
    var user_equip      = $('select[name=equip] option:selected').val();
    //var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if(user_name==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_email==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_phone=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    if(user_quant=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_date=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if(proceed)
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response){

            //load json data from server and output message
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#form-elements input, #form-elements textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "teste@hotmail.com.br"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Orçamento do site'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userDate"]) || !isset($_POST["userQuant"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =                  $_POST["userPhone"];
    $user_Date =                  $_POST["userDate"];
    $user_Config       = filter_var($_POST["userConfig"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Quant =                  $_POST["userQuant"];
    $user_Equip       = filter_var($_POST["userEquip"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    //$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'O campo nome não pode ficar vazio'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ultilize um e-mail válido'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Phone)<5) //check emtpy phone
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira um número de telefone'));
        die($output);
    }


    if(strlen($user_Date)<5) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira uma data para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }

     if(strlen($user_Quant)<2) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira a quantidade de pessoas para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Data do Evento: </strong>". $user_Date ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Quantidade de pessoas: </strong>". $user_Quant ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Configurações do evento: </strong>". $user_Config ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Equipamentos: </strong>". $user_Equip ."<br>";
    //$message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8';



    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

console.log[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou sem a parte de `option:selected` nos selectors dos selects? Sem isso irá retornar uma array somente com os valores selecionados.

Comment: @KillerJack se eu tirar isso essa parte do código retorna vazia no e-mail

Comment: Coloque `console.log(user_config);` após a declaração da variável no javascript e veja o resultado com e sem o `option:selected`. O problema de estar vazio deve ser porque agora é um array e não tem nenhum loop no seu código para percorrê-lo.

Comment: `var_dump` exibe o conteúdo na tela, não no devtools. `console.log` sim, aparece no devtools.

Comment: ficaria assim amigo var user_config     = console.log('select[name=config] option:selected').val(); está correto ?

Comment: Não, não modifique a definição da variável. Somente adicione `console.log(user_config);` em outra linha, abaixo dessa que define a variável e veja o que aparece no devtools.

Comment: Pronto amigo coloquei na pergunta la o console do google e a linha onde inseri o console

Comment: Amigo fiz melhor adicionei a linha de código que vc mandou direto no console e printei e adicionei na pergunta deu undefined

Comment: Você precisa selecionar as coisas no select para poder ver o valor. Na imagem está undefined porque você não selecionou nada. Faça o teste que eu falei: Selecione dois ou mais valores com o `option:selected` e veja que só o último vai aparecer, depois tire o `option:selected` e faça o mesmo teste, verá que vai mostrar todos em um array.

Comment: @KillerJack Amigo eu adicionei o selected no meu código e executei o comando n console e mesmo assim deu erro no console aparece isso VM96:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: user_config is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13   som o sem selected ao rodar o comando da erro

Answer (score 1):

Você deve declarar o name do select como um array:

```
<select multiple name="config[]"></select>
```

Para transformar o array recebido em string você pode usar a função [implode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php).

Comment: ao declarar ele como array o nome que estava ai perder as referencias no código para chamar esse array no js e no php como faço ? desculpa pela pergunta sou iniciante em programação

Comment: No js talvez você não precise mudar. Verifique o valor de config no php com var_dump($_POST['config']); die;

Comment: ficaria assim meu código no php $user_Config       = var_dump($_POST["userConfig"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: O var_dump seria só pra você conferir o valor que o JS está enviando para o PHP.

Comment: vou verificar aqui e vou adicionar o print do console da pergunta para você analizar

Comment: Adicionei o print do console la na pergunta se puder dar uma olhada no meu código php adicionei essa linha  $user_Config       = var_dump($_POST["userConfig"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: Você não precisa e, na verdade, não deve adicionar o var_dump a uma variável. Simplesmente execute o comando e veja o que aparece na tela e não no devtools.

Comment: @KillerJack eu adicionei name="config[]" depois nos meus options deixei com selected para que no site mostre ja p campo selecionado e quando rodo o comando no console do navegagor aparece o erro Uncaught ReferenceError: var_dump is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Veja a documentação do [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: @RayannNayran esse é o comando que estou rodando no console  var_dump($_POST['config']); o config no caso seria o array que estou utilizando no meu selectpicker no caso ficou como name="config[]" igual esta na resposta acima porem só aparece um erro no cosole e não me retorna nenhum valor

Comment: O var_dump() é do PHP, você não deve executá-lo no console, e sim escrevê-lo  no seu código.